# Database first ORM

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am currently about to start out on a project to convert a legacy access front end application using MSSQL backend database to WPF using the MVVM pattern.

The database has around 300 tables so it will need to use and ORM tool to generate the POCO classes using database first driven design.

I have recently receiving some mentoring for the project and nHibernate has been recommended as the ORM over Entity.

Looking to find out your recommendations and whether we should be looking to Entity or another ORM as opposed to what is possibly just the one that the mentor  has experience using?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I'm using NHibernate everywhere. On .NET Core, on .NET Framework, since 2009. Only some projects that are not permitted use of NH i've used EF or other orm or some like this (Linq for SQL or DAAB stuff).

NHibernate provide more control, more configuration spots and more features instead EF. It's my recomendation in all scenarios that be use a ORM. Dapper solve some questions too. 
But if i have NH i don't need Dapper because we have some types of operate with database.

More options, more responsability. NHibernate is more complex. Needs a deep drive into your complexity to understand how give best performance and approach to solve any kind of database interaction. Do you do more, but you must know to do.